# Product of two automorphic form is still automorphic form?

Tags: automorphic-forms

I am wondering whether the automorphic forms in some automorphic representation is closed under product. I think it is true by definition of automorphic form. Am I right?

Comment: No. Very rarely would the tensor product of two irreducibles be irreducible. And, after all, already the Rankin-Selberg integral for two $GL2$ cuspforms against an Eisenstein series can be construed as computing the continuous-spectrum components of the tensor product, for example.

Comment: Perhaps the question means “product” in the sense of multiplication? E.g. akin to how the product of two classical modular forms of weight $k$ and $\ell$ is a modular form of weight $k + \ell$.

Comment: @paul, I mean multiplication of automorphic forms not tensor product of automorphic representations.

Comment: @Monty, yes, I assumed so: pointwise multiplication is tensor product of representations. It's anomalous that tensor products of holomorphic discrete series decompose discretely, and have a unique lowest among "lowest weight vectors", so in their discrete decomposition contain a copy of the predictable holomorphic discrete series.

Comment: @robinz16, as in my other comment: a pointwise product really is a tensor product of the corresponding repns. The holomorphic discrete series behave anomalously...